# IOS nested uiview

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a yellow uiview, inside it there is a blue view. 
But XCode and iPhone simulator show it different.

How to show in simulator like the left one?
[image]

Comment: Is it done programmatically or using storyboard? If it's programmatically could you please post some code

Comment: Try to set the yellow view's `clipsToBounds` property to YES.

Comment: I might be wrong but it looks like the storyboard is set up for the 4 inch screen and you're running the 3.5 inch screen simulator which means it's auto layout that's your problem

Comment: no code, only drag and drop, I will try clipsToBounds.

Comment: _view1.clipsToBounds = YES; it worked. Thanks